# TCP throughput vs Session graph

Tags: performance, sockets, networking, tcp, throughput

Does TCP throughput increase as Session increases ?

Eg.
 One connection to the Server -> TCP throughput = 93 Mbps (for 100 Mbps port).
will 10 connections aggr value to server increase or decrease the TCP throughput.

if so, how?

Also what are the factors affect the increase session to increase TCP throughput (like window size, MTU etc)?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, and for nothing else.

Comment: Maybe. Answer far to complex for this forum. Google each of slow start, window scaling, congestion control

Comment: Do you mean then as number of session increases  , Due to slow start - the time throughput at initial time will less.

Comment: Your apparent expectation that the TCP throughout will increase with the number of sessions is counter-intuitive, to say the least.